# linking an map to an API policy in apigee

Tags: api, apigee

I am trying to perform some basic authentication . I have created a `map` in apigee with an apikey and allowed user, Can anyone help me on how I could link this map to the `verify API key` policy .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are ApiKeys in your map generated via apigee or third party?
If they are generated in Apigee, then you can use VerifyAPIKey Straight away (To Validate key), then use [KeyValueMapPolicy](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/persist-data-using-keyvaluemap), "GET" operation to get, your users for that apikey, if that is your use case. 
If you are just storing the APIKey(generated via third party) in Map, in than you can just use GET on Key Value maps.

Comment: @abhisek Tyagi : I am generating the API key myself and storing those values in a map . I am trying to configure the policy to verify the apikey with the one I have stored in a map and then allow the request to hit the server .

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need an Verify API key policy to validate the the key which you have generated key. Just do the GET on the map you have created to validate. VerifyAPIKey policy will be used when a key is generated by Apigee.